# C# Export to PDF and ONLY add Columns, not include buttons

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview, itext

I've made a Password manager app.
Im trying to only export Name, Username, Password and Chaged date rows.
But for now, it also export the column buttons.

Any hints?

When I Export with this code:

```
  private void exportToPDFToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Pdf File |*.pdf";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();//Open Document to write

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("data Exported From PassVault!\n\n");
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dgvPasswords.Columns.Count);

            //Add the headers
            for (int j = 0; j < dgvPasswords.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgvPasswords.Columns[j].HeaderText));

            }

            //Flag the first row as header
            table.HeaderRows = 1;

            //Add the actual rows from the DGV to the table
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvPasswords.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dgvPasswords.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dgvPasswords[k, i].Value != null)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(dgvPasswords[k, i].Value.ToString()));

                    }
                }
            }

            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();
          //  MessageBox.Show("Exported as Export-List.pdf to \n\n" + Application.StartupPath + " /Export-List.pdf", "PDF Exported", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    }
```

It also includes the column Copy and Column New button..
Made It perfect, but now Im not sure where I did miss.

How do I only export: Name, Username, Password and Changed Date from DgvPassword?

Comment: Your `for` loop has the wrong bounds.

Comment: Any further info please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access outside the bounds of the dgvPasswords array due to using the incorrect upper limit for `k`

```
 for (int k = 0; k < dgvPasswords.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
```

should read

```
  for (int k = 0; k < dgvPasswords.Rows.Count; k++)
        {
```

Comment: Ahh of course edit Columns to Rows.. Thank you. It didnt reply with error and created the .pdf file only with the headertext and not the row contents..

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was my mistake. Do you know how I can choose  where to save the pdf file like savefileialog? I can do it with Excel, but not PDF

Comment: What is the namespace of PdfWriter and Document?

Comment: Document doc, Pdfwriter wri

Comment: I mean like Microsoft.Office.Document or similar. I don't know where these classes come from so can't tell you how to use them.

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop

Comment: It looks to me far more likely they are part of `iTextSharp.text`, in which case have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267719/save-pdf-file-with-user-input-filename-itextsharp)

Comment: Yes it is iTextSharp.text ad Itextsharp.pdf. Problem is with my rows and columns. Im trying to make it show Name, Username, Password and changed date only, not with the buttons included..

Comment: I suggest you start a new question as I've answered your first two then you've re-edited to add another one.

Comment: Nothing more to do seeing as you've already accepted the answer