# corrupt file when generating PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, sql, itext

Im trying to save a pdf file from my program as you can see on my code.

```
 private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvWord.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.Filter = " PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            save.FileName = "Result.pdf";
            bool ErrorMessage = false;
            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(save.FileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(save.FileName);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        ErrorMessage = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Can't write the data" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (!ErrorMessage)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PdfPTable pTable = new PdfPTable(dgvWord.Columns.Count);
                        pTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 2;
                        pTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
                        pTable.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                        foreach(DataGridViewRow viewRow in dgvWord.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach(DataGridViewCell dcell in viewRow.Cells)
                            {
                                pTable.AddCell(dcell.Value.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(save.FileName,FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 8f, 16f, 16f, 8f);
                            document.Open();
                            document.Add(pTable);
                            document.Close();
                            fileStream.Close();
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Data Export success"); 
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error while exporting data" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record");
        }
    }
```

this code if for the button for showing the data from my sql database.

```
 private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqdata = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Data", sqcon);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqdata.Fill(dt);

            dgvWord.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

I can save the file and i can see it from the directory on where i save the file, but i cant open it as a pdf file. The error is the file is not decoded properly. Can you help me as to where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you open the file manually? Is it really a PDF file? Maybe zero bytes?

Comment: How are the `filestream` and `document` variables connected? There doesn't seem to be any code here that actually writes the pdf to the stream.

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with the `fileStream` other than call `.Close` and then `.Dispose` implicitly via the `using`. That you do stuff with a `iTextSharp.text.Document` in the same area of the code is neither here nor there because you're not writing anything to the `fileStream`. I would expect an empty file.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30268108/3181933) will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually writing the PDF content to the file. iTextSharp requires you to use PdfWriter.GetInstance to attach the document to a fileStream.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(save.FileName,FileMode.Create))
{
    var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 8f, 16f, 16f, 8f);
    document.Open();

    // !!make sure the document can be written to the filestream
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
    
    document.Add(pTable);
    document.Close();

    writer.Close(); // <- close the writer

    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I should you to use for generate PDF:

```
            // create document
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

            // open document
            doc.Open();

            try
            {
                // For text and other options
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

                //
                //Write you code here
                //
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            

            // close document
            doc.Close();
```

I think is better put your code in a try-catch in order to prevent any errors.